# How to plot multiple time series (common x-axis with vertical facet) using Plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a Vertical stack plot for 4 time series in R. The following codes can show the figure, but the 'lty' and 'col' parameters are not working correctly. Meanwhile, although "main=NULL" is used, the title still shows. Is there any way to fix this?

In addition, is there any way to set the "xlim" for each small plot? Thank you.

```
data(UKgas)
ts1 = UKgas
ts2 = UKgas+100
ts3 = UKgas+500
ts4 = UKgas+1000

plot(ts.union(TS1 = ts1, TS2 = ts2,TS3 = ts3, TS4 = ts4), lty = 1:4, col = 1:4, main = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: did you consider unsing ggplot ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Sure thing, ggplot is very powerful. I am just curious to know how to fix the problem using the basic plot in R. Would you please provide an example using ggplot? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting a `ts.union` object calls the method `stats:::plot.ts`, and from looking at the source code, this will only take a single color I'm afraid. You can get the result you want using a little data wrangling and `ggplot2`, with the added benefit that the plot is fully customizable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ts_s  <- ts.union(TS1 = ts1, TS2 = ts2,TS3 = ts3, TS4 = ts4)
times <- attr(ts_s, "tsp")
df    <- cbind(as.data.frame(ts_s), year = seq(times[1], times[2], 1/times[3]))

ggplot(pivot_longer(df, 1:4), aes(year, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = name)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 1985, 5)) +
  facet_grid(name~., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  labs(title = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "npc"),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 16, face = 2),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you very much for the detailed example! I wonder if it is possible to set axis ticks for each facet (TS1, TS2, TS3, and TS4) in the plot? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang you can add the argument `scales = "free_y"` to the `facet_grid` call, which will change the y axis to the most appropriate range for each facet. I'll update to demonstrate. If you want very specific axis ticks, you can add a `scale_y_continuous` call to your plot, with the argument `breaks = ...`, where `...` is the vector of breaks you want to use.

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks a lot for your explanation and updated codes. To extend this topic a bit, I wonder if it is possible to manually set y-axis ticks for each facet (4 in total)? For example, we want to have y-axis ticks (250, 500, 750, 100, 1250) for TS1 and (300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500) for TS2. Thank you.